# Retrieving top 3 from database and put into hhomepage

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I have a database that contains all the lastest news. I want the homepage to only display the latest three news items.

My aspx page is setup as:

```
<div class="row"> 
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptNewsList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
             <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
                 <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
             </h2>           
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-4">              
              <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
                 <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
             </h2>            
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-4">              
             <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
                 <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
             </h2>            
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater> 
</div>
```

My aspx.cs page is setup as follows, I am using a repeater and the repeater loads the same news into the three columns

I would like col 1 to have latest news and col 2 to have latest news -1 and col 3 to have latest news -2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptNewsList.DataSource = GetNewsList();
        rptNewsList.DataBind();
    }
    private DataTable GetNewsList()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string query = "SELECT top 1 [Id], [Title], [DatePosted], [NewsContent] FROM [News] ORDER BY [Id] DESC";
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        connection.Close();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

My table is configured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] (
[Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[DatePosted]  DATE           NOT NULL,
[NewsContent] NTEXT          NOT NULL,
[IsRead]      BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

[image: This is currently being display which is the latest news displayed 3 times]

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 [Id], [Title], [DatePosted], [NewsContent] FROM [News] 
ORDER BY [DatePosted] DESC
```

Comment: Hi, My problem is that my latest news appears 3 times in the home page. I want the 3 three news items. In the image I attached, it show the latest news item is displayed three times instead of one

Comment: Try running this query manually on the DB? Or try it out in your code and see what happens. You were using "SELECT TOP 1" which was grabbing the latest and repeating it three times in your front end.

Comment: Hi IrishChieftain, that's what I am currently running and this outputs the latest news three time. This is on Row 1 across 3 columns.

Comment: Weird, are you sure you don't have duplicate entries in your DB? Note that I also changed the ORDER BY clause...

Comment: I'm updating the answer to include "DISTINCT".